# How to add a button in the TableviewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I was wondering how to add a simple static button at the bottom right of the Tableviewcontroller background, its will be contact infos.

I have tried through through the storyboard with no success.Do you have any clue for that?

Thank you  ,

Regards,

[image]

Comment: in this case you have to add the button to UIView, not to UITableViewController

Comment: @Burnie777 yes exactly i want the button bellow the cells of the tableview. If I use a normal view controller and add a tableviewcell not sure i could obtain this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Take ViewController and Add TableView inside it.
Take one View and set the bottom of the view controller and set button inside that View.

Comment: Yeah that great but does the button will be always visible ? I would like it to be covered by the cell.

Comment: put top contraint of view to the bottom of tableView

Comment: [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,100,0)]; use this

Answer (score 1):

Create a `UIView` with `UIButton` and set this view as TableView's `FooterView`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make a normal ViewController, add a tableView and save an space for that button, take note that you have to set the delegates and datasource for that tableview.

Answer (score 0):

You could use footerView if you want this button to appear only at the bottom of the whole TableViewController. To do that, you can drag a view after the cell in the hierarchy:

[image: tableview hierarchy with footerview]

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to use a `UITableViewController`, you could create a normal `UIViewController`, add a container in it and embed a `UITableViewController` in the container. Here's an example:

[image: Embedded TableViewController]